# Magento: add custom column in the admin customers grid

Tags: php, magento, customization

I wrote my own Magento function which calculates the percentage relation of orders to retours. In this way you can categorize customers into those, who never give bought things back (green - good customers), who sometimes make retours (yellow) and those ones, who return most of bought things (red - bad customers).

For this, I added a new db table which saves required information.

Now, I would like to add a new column in Magento's admin Customers->Manage customers which shows the appropriate color. I managed to add the header of the new column, but I have no clue how to show my custom calculations from my custom db table. Magento makes everything so complicated.

I edited the "app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php" and added the following code into the "prepareColumns":

```
    $this->addColumn('abc', array(
      'header' => "ABC"
    ));
```

So, how do I fill it with any data?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simplest solution is to edit the `prepareCollection` function in the same class, and join your table to the results set. Then you simply have to set the correct index in your `addColumn` definition and the column should be populated.

Ideally of course you shouldn't be editing the core files, a slightly better option would be to instead rewrite the class, or you could go the whole hog and [do it with events](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/07/27/adding-order-attribute-to-orders-grid-in-magento-1-4-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

So do you maybe know how do to this? What do all the parameters exactly mean?:

```
    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```

Please give me any piece of advice. Let's say, I would just make a raw SQL query for each customer, make some calculations and put it out. I only need the customer's id to do this.